# Suggestion to use charts api with Angular 6

Tags: graph, charts, highcharts, google-visualization, angular6

I am new to Angular 6, and I have requirement to implement charts/graph in my web application.
I am looking for suggestions which one is good option to integrate with Angular 6

```
1. High Charts
2. Google Developer Charts 
3. D3.js 
4. etc etc
```

Please help me to select right chart for my application.

My basic requirement for chart is

```
Dynamic change of x,y-axis interval.
I can download the charts 
I want to display the stacked chart example for different accounts.
```

Thanks in advance for your replies !!

Comment: Highcharts will be a perfect choice. Check `highcharts-angular` wrapper: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Answer (score 0):

HighChart seems to be good option for my scenario, as it caters all my needs and even give more flexibility for charts.
Thanks !!